# Inserting numerical ID's in paragraphs (PHP/MySQL DB Query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a pretty ordinary query that displays articles stored in a database table (field = 'Article')...

```
while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $Content = $row['Article'];
}

echo $Content;
```

I'd like to know how I can modify the display so that every paragraph has a numerical ID. For example, the first paragraph would be [p id="1"], the second one [p id="2"] and so on. However, it would be even better if the last paragraph displayed as [p id="Last"].

(Sorry, I forgot how to post inline code, so I replaced the tags (e.g. <) with brackets.)

My goal is to simply get more control over my content. For example, there are certain items that I want to include after the first paragraph on some pages, and I might want to include a certain feature before paragraph#4 on one special page.

---

**ON EDIT**... Neither of the methods suggested below worked for me, but it' probably because I simply didn't implement them correctly; the code in both examples isn't familiar to me. At any rate, I'm bookmarking this page so I can learn more about those scripts.

In the meantime, I finally found a regex solution. (I think preg_replace is another word for regex, right?)

This inserts a numerical ID in each paragraph tag:

```
$c = 1;
$r = preg_replace('/(<p( [^>]+)?>)/ie', '"<p\2 id=\"" . $c++ . "\">"', $Article);
$Article = $r;
```

This changes the ID in the last paragraph tag to "**Last**"...

```
$c = 1;
$r = preg_replace('/(<p( [^>]+)?>)/ie', '"<p\2 id=\"" . $c++ . "\">"', $Article);
$r = preg_replace('/(<p.*?)id="'.($c-1).'"(>)/i', '\1id="Last"\2', $r);
$Article = $r;
```

Comment: Is there one paragraph per row fetched from the table server? Or do you have to split the text retrieved by each `fetch()` method call into multiple paragraphs?

Comment: No, I've stored entire articles in the table. For example, the row where Article = 'Wildebeest' might contain an article with fourteen paragraphs. I should have added that the first paragraph in most of my articles has a class - [p class="pfirst"]. So the finished product would look like [p class="pfirst" id="1"] or [p id="1" class="pfirst"]. However, if that first paragraph didn't have a numerical ID at all, it would be fine, since it's easy to insert things before the entire article or before paragraph#2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML is well-formed, you could use the [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) class to do so:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($row['Article']);
$i = 0;
foreach ($sxe->children() as $p) {
    $p->addAttribute('id', $i);
}
$p->id = 'Last'; // to set the ID of the last paragraph
echo $sxe->__toString();
```

If it isn't well-formed, you could use the [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class instead:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($row['Article']);
$i;
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $p) {
    $p->id = $id;
}
$p->id = 'Last';
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks, but, using the first method, I get an error message on the first line: "String could not be parsed as XML." (When you say "well formed," I assume you mean my HTML isn't sloppy; it has the correct tags, for example - right?)